# Camel "Succesfull delivery acknowledgements"

Tags: java, oracle, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have been trying to come up with a camel route that would read from an activemq and write to Oracle AQ.

However, when a message is succesfully written to Oracle-aq, I have to write a successful message to another Active mq queue("something like message with id 41 has been sent to OracleAQ")

Is there any "Auto-acknowledge" type of feature in camel that can be useful here?

This is the basic route that i have that routes from active mq to oracle aq.

```
<route>
    <from uri="jms:queue:Q.Customer1"/>
        <setHeader headerName="prop">
        <simple>header1Value</simple>
        </setHeader>
    <to uri="oracleQueue:queue:Q.Customer2"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another `to` that points to the queue you want camel to post to after it writes to oracle, like so:

```
<onException>
    <exception>some.sql.Exception</exception>
    <to uri="some:error:handler:uri" /> <!-- like a bean or dead letter channel or whatever -->
</onException>
<route>
    <from uri="jms:queue:Q.Customer1"/>
    <setHeader headerName="prop">
        <simple>header1Value</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="oracleQueue:queue:Q.Customer2"/>
    <!-- this step will not be called until the previous one is finished  -->
    <to uri="jms:queue:SomeOtherQueue"/>
</route>
```

Comment: That would not mean the message was succesfully written to Oracle...right?...I only need to write it to a different queue when the message gets succesfully written to oracle aq

Comment: When you say "successfully" written, do you mean the DB transaction is finished and the record is present in the DB? Unless you are doing this work in parallel (which you are not according to the route definition), Camel will not move onto the next step until the current step is finished. So if it makes it `<to uri="jms:queue:SomeOtherQueue"/>`, that means the record made it in the DB. If there is a chance of errors, then you setup an error handler for your route and all failed executions will go there, not to your final queue. Hope this helps. Updated code sampe too.

Comment: "Succesfull" means, the message has reached Oracle queue. I do not care what Oracle does with it. I only care when message was written to Oracle.

Comment: The example in the answer will do it.

Comment: Lets say, there was an error or exception during the first "to". It is finished, but there was an error during 1. Would the second "to" happen?.....Thanks for the responses...

Comment: You'll need to add an error handler, check out the updated example.